# How can I stop brew prune and brew upgrade from fighting?

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source

I am running Homebrew on 10.13.6, with the prefix `/usr/local`.

When I run `brew upgrade`, two directories are created in `/usr/local/share`.  These are: `/usr/local/share/man/man2`, and `/usr/local/share/man/man6`.  There are no files in these directories.

Meanwhile, whenever I run `brew prune --verbose`, I get the output:

```
rmdir /usr/local/share/man/man6
rmdir /usr/local/share/man/man2
Pruned 0 symbolic links and 2 directories from /usr/local
```

Whenever `brew upgrade`, these two troublesome directories are then re-created! The cycle continues, on and on and on.  I have repeatedly run `brew update`, `brew cleanup`, and `brew doctor`.  I have even reinstalled Homebrew and all my packages.  Yet, the eternal battle between `brew upgrade` and `brew prune` continues.

How can I get them to stop fighting?

Comment: That looks like a homebrew bug - best to report it

Comment: Not seeing any point to homebrew, I've never bothered with it, but answer me this... why do you care?  Some package you have installed, creates man2 ("Unix and C system calls") and man6 ("Games"), and doesn't put anything in them.  The later --prune removes them again, since they're empty.  That seems to be the function of --prune?

Answer (score 2):

There is an inelegant solution to this bug/inconsistency in the two functions of the tools: put any file in the directories in question.

Then  `brew prune` will stop removing them because they will no longer be empty.  If `brew prune` is no longer removing them, `brew upgrade` won't create them.  If you're concerned about space, you could even put an alias file in the directories.

In the grand scheme of things, having these empty folders create and then removed is a harmless side effect and doesn’t really break anything functionally.